# delayed_jobs error, undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

the gem delayed_jobs works perfectly in development enviroment. But in production, it doesnot work. It throws the following error in the logs

Am using this delayed_job to send emails to users

```
I, [2013-11-20T13:55:28.418252 #31220]  INFO -- : 2013-11-20T13:55:28+0000: 
[Worker(delayed_job host:li483-234 pid:31220)] 1 jobs processed at 77.3979 j/s, 1 failed
I, [2013-11-20T14:05:48.680718 #31220]  INFO -- : 2013-11-20T14:05:48+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:li483-234 pid:31220)] Job Class#receive_msg (id=1) RUNNING
E, [2013-11-20T14:05:48.683409 #31220] ERROR -- : 2013-11-20T14:05:48+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:li483-234 pid:31220)] Job Class#receive_msg (id=1) FAILED (5 prior attempts) with NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

any clues?

Comment: `nil.email`. Okay, now that I've been able to create a reproduction test-case for you, find out *why* there is a nil when it's not expected.

Comment: Thanks for very fast response. I found the answer, I have shown below

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

in `config/application.rb` place this on top

```
require 'yaml'
```

YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'

restart server and RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start